# Is practicing laining considered learning Torah?

Tags: torah-study, torah-reading, trop-cantillation

Is practicing laining for a Parsha considered Talmud Torah?

Namely, does this "count" as Torah learning, would one get *s'char* for this etc **OR** could it be considered more like memorizing a song?

Sources welcome- thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I asked my LOR about whether I could practice laining on Tishah B'Av, and was told that I shouldn't since it was considered learning Torah on Tishah B'Av

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/99842/13438

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27898/learning-torah-without-understanding

Comment: @Alex not necessarily that a person doesn't understand- rather is studying to memorize the tune (and maybe not  considered "learning" since it's not really his intention/ he's just doing it to memorize the tune)

Comment: Why focus on studying? Ask more generally: does Leining in Shul count as Talmud Torah or is it considered more like singing a song?

Comment: @DoubleAA reading in shul is a mitzvah, which might be different than practicing.

Comment: @larry wearing tzitzit is a mitzva but it's not considered learning. If you're just trying to sing, what does it matter what mitzva you are also performing?

Answer (score 4):

The Shulchan Aruch HaRav Talmud Torah 2/12-13 writes that there is a difference between the 24 seforim of the written Torah, where saying the words is a mitzvah even if you don't understand the meaning of those words. While the oral Torah is a mitzvah only when you understand it.

> אך אם מוציא בשפתיו אע"פ שאינו מבין אפי' פירוש המילות מפני שהוא עם הארץ
>   הרי זה מקיים מצות ולמדתם. ולפיכך כל עם הארץ מברך ברכת התורה בשחר לפני
>   הפסוקים וכן כשעולה לספר תורה:
>
> במה דברים אמורים בתורה שבכתב, אבל בתורה שבעל פה אם אינו מבין הפירוש
>   אינו נחשב לימוד כלל

Based on that, each word you read when practicing laining a parsha would be a mitzvah.

Comment: Thanks! But what's to say one doesn't understand it? Rather that one is just learning the accompanying tune to chant the Torah portion- not the words themselves

Comment: I downvoted because he contradicts the Talmud.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel how?

Comment: But in the case you quote from shulchan aruch, the difference is in the intent, whereby in the example given the person's intent is for learning as opposed to the OP's question where his intent is not for learning.